# Does Virtual Box Support Guest Suspend/Hibernate?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hibernate, suspend

I set up a Debian VM using Virtual Box to experiment with suspend/hibernation when LUKS is enabled. But I don't seem to be able to sleep the guest. **My question is not about setting up hibernation.**

I tried hibernation with `systemctl hibernate` and suspend with clicking the **SLEEP** button at the guest power management menu. They both resulted in a non-responsive black screen. After experiencing black screen, I tried to send `ACPI Shutdown` signal. First, using the *Machine* menu, then by pressing `HOST+H`. They both had no effect. I also tried to send the shutdown signal from the host terminal with the following command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "debian_vm_name" acpisleepbutton
```

But it also didn't help.

Is Virtual Box not supporting guest suspend or hibernate?

**UPDATE 1:** I set up a new VM without LUKS to try suspending. Installed Virtual Box Guest Additions, too. Still, guest suspend is not working.

**UPDATE 2:** QEMU/KVM also did not work.

Comment: It's not recommended to use sleep/hibernate from the guest - you would usually use "Save the machine state" from the host (`HOST+Q`). That said, `HOST+H` *should* normally wake a VM stuck in sleep/hibernate mode, so it may be an issue with that VM specifically

Comment: Saving the machine state isn’t helpful for OP if the goal is to test Suspend-to-RAM. // I’m not aware of any hypervisor that emulates ACPI S3 Suspend-to-RAM. There are lots of hardware quirks involved, so testing on a real PC is the only meaningful way IMHO.